# How to Import Bluemix project to android studio?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I want to import my bluemix project to android studio but I was unable to find how to do it. If you know how to import project  please share this information.

Comment: Where is your project currently? Is it in Jazzhub?

Answer (score 0):

To get started with an Android Bluemix project, [choose a starter here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/mobile/create-project/), add capabilities, and download the code.

Subsequently, open up Android Studio and click the **Open an existing Android Studio Project** button and select your project.

[image: android studio]